# How do I give users the ability to swipe through an array of images in swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm currently using a combination of UISwipeGestureRecognisers and an array of images but this isn't giving me the desired effect. When I swipe the image just appears but what I'm aiming for is a horizontal scrolling effect.

So for example if I partially scroll to the left, both the image I'm scrolling away from and the image I'm scrolling to will be on screen. I'm sure this can be achieved with a horizontal UIScrollView but not sure how to do this.

This is what I'm doing now.

**My images are loaded from parse and stored in a imagesArray:**

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: Array!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("0 images found")
        } else {


            self.imagesArray.addObjectsFromArray(objects)
```

**Set up the gesture recogniser in my viewDidload:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe:")
    userImage.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe:")

    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    userImage.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
}
```

**My didSwipe method:**

```
func didSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    var direction = sender.direction as UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection

    switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        println("swiped right")

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        println("swiped left")
        println(imagesArray)
        userImage.file = imagesArray.objectAtIndex(1)["image"] as PFFile
        userImage.loadInBackground()
    default:
        println("ok")

    }


}
```

Comment: You don't need custom gesture recognizers; a scroll view will make the content scrollable for you. Perhaps you want to set `pagingEnabled=YES`.