# accessing an array of images from 1 view controller to another, to add swipe gesture recognizer

Tags: swift

i have a collection view which has an array of images. when i press on any of the images it will open that image in full screen in another class. i tried to add swipe gesture recognizer in the second view controller but i dont know how to access the array that is in the first view controller.

This is my first view controller that displays the images in collection view

```
class sowrController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var albums = [AlbumModel]()
    let db : DBHelperMo2lfat = DBHelperMo2lfat()
    var selectedIndex : Int = -1


    var posts : Post!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.albums.removeAll()
        self.albums.append(contentsOf: self.db.fetchAllImages())
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS_SOWR.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                self.albums.removeAll()
                for snap in snapshot {
                    print ("SNAP: \(snap)")

                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                        let album : AlbumModel = AlbumModel(id: postDict["id"] as! String, name: postDict["image_name"] as! String, path: postDict["image_path"] as! String, url: postDict["image_path"] as! String, localPath: "")

                        if let items = snap.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                            for itemSnap in items {
                                if let albumSnap = itemSnap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                    album.childAlbums.append(AlbumModel(id: albumSnap["id"] as! String, name: albumSnap["image_name"] as! String, path: albumSnap["image_path"] as! String, url: albumSnap["image_path"] as! String, localPath: ""))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.albums.append(album)

                    }
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }

        })

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return self.albums.count

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.BookCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? collectionViewCellSowr {

            let album = albums[indexPath.item]
            cell.initWithAlbumModel(album: album)

            return cell
        }else {
            return collectionViewCellSowr()
        }

    }

    private struct Constants {
        static let BookCellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAlbum", sender: self)
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "showAlbum"
        {

            let vc = segue.destination as! imageFullScreen

            vc.images = self.albums[self.selectedIndex]

        }
    }
```

This is the second view controller that makes the images go in full screen

```
class imageFullScreen: UIViewController{


    var images : AlbumModel?
    let db : DBHelperMo2lfat = DBHelperMo2lfat()

    @IBAction func pictureSwipe(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var caption: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.caption.text = images?.imageName
        let url =  URL(string: (images?.imagePath)!)
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: [.progressiveDownload,.retryFailed])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, so here is a collection view controller that creates image view as a subview and responding to swipe gestures. Please make sure you have two images "Image" and "Image-1" in your assets folder.

```
//
//  CollectionViewController.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Yonatan Vainer on 05/08/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Sensus Healthcare LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "id"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
    var index = 0;
    let names = ["Image","Image-1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //For left swipe
        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.goLeft(_:)))
        left.direction = .left
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(left)

        //For right swipe
        let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.goRight(_:)))
        right.direction = .right
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(right)

        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.layoutSubviews()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return names.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell
        let nail = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        nail.image = UIImage(named: names[indexPath.row])

        cell.backgroundView = nail
        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: names[indexPath.row])
        index = indexPath.row
    }

    func goLeft(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        index += 1
        if index<0{
            index = 0
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: names[index])
    }

    func goRight(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        index -= 1
        if index>1{
            index = 1
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: names[index])
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {

    }
    */

}
```

==================================================================

In storyboard, click on your collection view and embed navigation controller.
This will add a top bar with the back button.
Attached [image]image.

Comment: what i am trying to do is scroll right and left between an array of images, similar to any image gallery

Comment: Ok. There are few options. Here is one: In that case, don't use the second view controller. On any cell click inside the collection view controller, create programmatically UIImageView, populate it with your image, make it in full screen by assigning width and height, and add it as a subview. Then when you get a swipe gesture, just assign different image and reload the view.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Checked it on my simulator and it works fine. If it is what you need, you are welcome to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, because I don't understand what the array has to do with a gesture recognizer, but if you are just trying to access the array from the previous ViewController, this should work *if you have a navigation controller* :

```
let vcIndex = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.index(where: { (viewController) -> Bool in

            if let _ = viewController as? sowrController {
                return true
            }
            return false
})

let prevVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[vcIndex!] as! sowrController
let albums:[AlbumModel] = prevVC.albums
```

Comment: @abdo Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123895/how-do-i-give-users-the-ability-to-swipe-through-an-array-of-images-in-swift). Duncan C's answer is exactly what you need.